# Why beans (with request scope) are not initialized in every request in controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

My ActionResponse code is :

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ActionResponse{
   public int a;
//body
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/ajax/discussion")
public class DiscussionController extends AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    private ActionResponse actionResponse;

    public void setActionResponse(ActionResponse actionResponse) {
        this.actionResponse = actionResponse;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public @ResponseBody String test(){
        String response=this.actionResponse.a+"";
        if(this.actionResponse.a==0)
            this.actionResponse.a=10;
        return response;
    }

}
```

I start the project and then the first time I request /ajax/discussion/test it shows 0

but after that for other requests it shows 10

It has to show 0 in every request because of request scope for ActionResponse

The question is:
Why the bean(ActionResponse) is created once not in every request?!!!

Comment: there is no @ScopedProxy .I can't find it in spring's reference.

Answer (score 4):

CGLIB works on class level.

CGLIB proxy is still a singleton, so it inherits the fields from the base class. When you change its public properties you change the values of the singleton.

You should encapsulate your data changes in public getters and setters.

Answer (score 3):

Was a little late - Just adding on to Boris Treukhov's answer(have +1'd it):

The reason is that since you have annotated ActionResponse with `@Scope(proxyMode=..)` Spring ends up creating a CGLIB subclass of this ActionResponse which internally handles the scope appropriately.

Now when you inject ActionResponse into the DiscussionController it is the CGLIB proxy that gets injected, and since you are setting the fields directly with going through the setter, it just modifies the fields of the proxy and not the underlying scoped proxied object. The fix is simply to make state changes via the getters and setters not through fields.

Comment: +1 I wonder if there are any good reference articles in the internet regarding CGLIB proxies, the same questions seem to emerge again and again.